# xml parser issue using lxml python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using server specific data and want to parse data "measTypes" in my xml file. because of some header data in my xml file (namespaces), I could not parse data, and my code fails, Could you help me to fetch "measTypes" in my xml data?

I am using below code, but it fails because measInfo has no value :

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(open("BLRNCH03.xml"))
measInfo = tree.xpath('//measInfo[@measInfoId="67109488"]')[0]
print(measInfo)
```

here is my xml data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<measCollecFile xmlns="http://latest/nmc-omc/cmNrm.doc#measCollec" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://latest/nmc-omc/cmNrm.doc#measCollec schema\pmResultSchedule.xsd">
    <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.435 V7.2" vendorName="Huawei">
        <fileSender elementType="BSC6910 UMTS"/>
        <measCollec beginTime="2018-04-22T00:00:00+04:30"/>
    </fileHeader>
    <measData>
    <measInfo measInfoId="67109481">
        <measTypes>67194793 67194794 67194795 67194796 </measTypes>
    </measInfo>
    <measData>
    <fileFooter>
        <measCollec endTime="2018-04-22T01:00:00+04:30"/>
    </fileFooter>
</measCollecFile>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [bind the default namespace to a prefix](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes) and use it in the `.xpath()` call.

I used the prefix `mc`, but you could use something different.

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree

namespaces = {"mc": "http://latest/nmc-omc/cmNrm.doc#measCollec"}

tree = etree.parse("BLRNCH03.xml")
measTypes = tree.xpath("//mc:measInfo[@measInfoId='67109481']/mc:measTypes", 
                      namespaces=namespaces)[0]

print(measTypes)
```

This will print something like:

```
<Element {http://latest/nmc-omc/cmNrm.doc#measCollec}measTypes at 283e638>
```

Comment: I'll give you an up vote so at least you get some of the points you deserve :)

Comment: @DanielHaley, sorry, I am new here, I did. My ponts are less than 15, I cannot give point to you, sorry about that :)

Comment: @Sadegh - That's quite ok. Thank you for accepting my answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!